# Installing Couenne solver on Python's Pymo extension

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyomo

How do I install the Pyomo's "Cuenne" optimizer extension? I have downloaded the binaries from: https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Couenne/

Here is an official guide from Pyomo's site on how to solve problems, with ASL:

> The basic work flow that takes place above can be summarized as:
>
> Create an ASL solver plugin that uses the ipopt executable appearing
> in the shell search PATH.
>
> Output the Pyomo model as an NL file. Invoke the solver (which
> produces an SOL file).
>
> Check the solver termination condition stored in the results object.
>
> Load the solution stored in the results object into the Pyomo model.Construct a Pyomo model.
>
> Solve the PyomoRead the SOL file into a Pyomo results object.

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/asl_io/asl_io.ipynb

But it doesn't detail how to get Pyomo to recognize the Couenne solver at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the Couenne executable is in your PATH environment variable. You will know this is done correctly if you can open a terminal and type `couenne` and get the following output:

```
$ couenne
Couenne 0.5.6 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization
Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne
No stub!
usage: couenne [options] stub [-AMPL] [<assignment> ...]

Options:
    --  {end of options}
    -=  {show name= possibilities}
    -?  {show usage}
    -bf {read boundsfile f}
    -e  {suppress echoing of assignments}
    -of {write .sol file to file f}
    -s  {write .sol file (without -AMPL)}
    -v  {just show version}
```

Similarly you should open a terminal and verify that Pyomo is successfully installed. Once you verify those two things then you can use Couenne from Pyomo simply by specifying `'couenne'` as the solver.

Comment: Can you give more details about ""open a terminal"? Where, command prompt? anconda prompt? ...

Answer (score 4):

For those who struggle what Bethany`s answer means in practice (like I did). Copy the couenne.exe file into the same folder as eg. ipopt.exe (e.g.: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin)