# I do not understand how to install IPOPT and COUENNE with PYOMO : Can you tell me how to do it?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyomo, ipopt

I have built a model with PYOMO. Now, I want to run it wih Couenne (or ipopt). I have downloaded the binaries for COUENNE 0.3.2 Windows as available by COIN-OR, and added the "bin" subfile (which cointain both ipopt.exe and couenne.exe) to the PATH environment variable in Windows.

But it does not work : when I set : `solver = pyo.SolverFactory('ipopt')`, the result is

```
ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'
```

If I try to call couenne by entering `solver = pyo.SolverFactory('couenne')`, the result is :

```
    RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "couenne"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
    executable: couenne
    type: couenne
    _args: ()
    options: {}
```

I have tried what was mention in these answers : [Installing Couenne solver on Python's Pymo extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055852/installing-couenne-solver-on-pythons-pymo-extension) , but to no avail

I am quite a beginner with solvers, and the way to get and install them puzzles me a lot...

Comment: Did you completely log out or restart your machine after the installs to register the adjustments to the path variable?  You should / must be able to call each of the solvers' executables from the command line and get an intelligent response.  `ipopt` or `couenne` from the command must work

Comment: I did. The is also no reaction when I type couenne (or ipopt) in cmd. If I specify in cmd the folder where the .exe files are, there is a reaction : CMD feeds back :

"No stub!
usage: ipopt [options] stub [-AMPL] [<assignment> ...]" (or couenne[options] for the couenne command)

Comment: It does sound like you have a path definition error. What about passing the absolute path to the IPOPT executable to `pyo.SolverFactory`?

Comment: I tried by doing `solverpath_folder='D:\Py_util\Couenne-0.3.2-win32-msvc9\bin'`, then ` solverpath_exe='D:\Py_util\Couenne-0.3.2-win32-msvc9\bin\couenne.exe'` , i.e. the path where the exe are stored. Then `solver= pyo.SolverFactory(solvername,executable=solverpath_exe)`. But it still returns 'Attempting to use an unavailable solver.'